# Charts does not display with DataPoint in OxyPlot MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, oxyplot

I have a problem with DataPoint. Charts does not display anything, and I hope to find out why.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12" x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestSeries}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <oxy:Plot Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <!--<oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding TestSeries.Value}"/>-->
                    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" />
                </oxy:Plot>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Button Width="100" Content="TestButtonAdd"/>
                    <Button Width="100" Content="TestButtonMinus"/>
                    <Button Width="100" Content="TestButton"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Test1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53"/>
                <Label Content="Test2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53"/>
                <Label Content="Test3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53"/>
                <Label Content="Test4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
                <Label Content="Test5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It is no problem with items, but it does not see Series.

```
using OxyPlot;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication12
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Dictionary<string, OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries> testSeries;
    public  Dictionary<string, OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries> TestSeries
    {
        get { return testSeries; }
        set { testSeries = value; }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries Test = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
        Test.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,10));
        Test.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 10));

        OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries Test1 = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
        Test1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 10));
        Test1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 10));

        TestSeries = new Dictionary<string,OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries>();
        TestSeries.Add("1",Test);
        TestSeries.Add("2",Test1);

        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Output does not show any binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to. And it's working.

```
using OxyPlot;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace WpfApplication12
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, IList<DataPoint>> testSeries;
    public Dictionary<string, IList<DataPoint>> TestSeries
    {
        get { return testSeries; }
        set { testSeries = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TestSeries"); }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        TestSeries = new Dictionary<string, IList<DataPoint>>();
        TestSeries.Add("1", new List<DataPoint> { new DataPoint(1, 2), new DataPoint(2, 3) });
        TestSeries.Add("2", new List<DataPoint> { new DataPoint(1, 3), new DataPoint(2, 1) });

        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
}
```